# Determine the order and commutativity of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

All matrices of the form

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, produce a group with respect to the matrix multiplication.

I want to show that every element (except the neutral one) is of order 3.

What I first did, was to compute

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3a & 3b +3ac \\
0 & 1 & 3c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2a & 2b +2ac \\
0 & 1 & 2c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now it  is obvious, since $3a \cong0\  \pmod 3$ and analogously for the other entries.

I assume this to be correct so far.

However, I wasn't able to show that this group is not commutative with respect to the matrix multiplication.

Comment: How about picking a couple of "random" elements, and multiply them both ways?

Comment: And a detail in the terminology. You have computed the order of the elements of the group. However, the order of the group itself is its cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&a'&b'\\0&1&c'\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

The upper right entry of the result is $b'+ac'+b$, so you need two matrices such that $ac'\neq a'c$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Calculate $AB$ and $BA$. You will find $AB\neq BA$. Therefore, the group cannot be commutative.